# Google authentication

Tags: google-authentication

I got a problem on google authenticate, it worked for a month but since a few days I got this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 
'Invalid token format' in /home/project/html/google/auth/apiOAuth2.php:127 Stack trace:
#0 /home/project/html/google/auth/apiOAuth2.php(89): apiOAuth2->setAccessToken('{? "access_tok...')
#1 /home/project/html/google/apiClient.php(132): apiOAuth2->authenticate(Array)
#2 /home/project/html/hk/connects/google.php(22): apiClient->authenticate()
#3 {main} thrown in /home/project/html/google/auth/apiOAuth2.php on line 127
```

In apiOAuth2.php I have the code :

```
$accessToken = json_decode($accessToken, true);
if (! isset($accessToken['access_token']) || ! isset($accessToken['expires_in']) || ! isset($accessToken['refresh_token'])) {
  throw new apiAuthException("Invalid token format");
}
```

I noticed that google doesn't send me the $accessToken['refresh_token'].
It doesn't seem to come from google cause I did a correct connexion on http://stackoverflow.com

Maybe it's cause of my code :

```
session_start();

$client = new apiClient();
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
  header('Location: '.$client->createAuthUrl()); // Calls the same page
} else {
  $client->authenticate(); // Fails at this level
}
```

EDIT:

I figured a way to do it, like I don't know what is refresh_token made for I added this line :

```
if (!isset($accessToken['refresh_token'])) $accessToken['refresh_token'] = 12345678910;
```

It works for the moment...

Comment: I figured a way out, See my Edit.

Comment: can you share some more of your code, i keep trying but i cant get over that fatal error, thanks

Comment: Hi Patrioticcow, In apiOAuth2.php you search for the code $accessToken = json_decode($accessToken, true); and just under you add the code that I edited in my review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new explicit parameter called "access_type" required by the google authentication api to obtain a valid refresh token.
With this parameter you declare that you need offline access to the account and the api provides you a refresh token.

Download the latest google PHP SDK that automatically handles the new required parameter